# How create View and Putting TextView inside it in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want add TextView inside View object in kotlin by code

I did create View but I can't add Text View in inside it

```
val view1 : View
  view1 = View(this)
  myLayout.addView(view1)
  view1.layoutParams.height = (Height * 0.35).toInt()
  view1.layoutParams.width = (Width * 0.8).toInt()
  view1.x = (1+ Width*0.10).toFloat()
  view1.y = (Height*0.15).toFloat()
  view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128,0,128))
```

Comment: "I can't add Text View in inside it" – Straight `View`s cannot have child `View`s. Only `ViewGroup`s can have children.

Comment: what is `myLayout`?

Comment: How I do that (ViewGroup)

Comment: myLayout is name id for layout in xml

Comment: no, that's not what I mean. before `myLayout.addView(view1)` you have to do something like `val myLayout = ...`

Comment: What I do now ? I want solve

Comment: It sounds like you are reimplementing constraint width percent, why not use a ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent view must be ViewGroup. For example:

```
val parent: ViewGroup = LinearLayout(context)
    parent.addView(yourTextView)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val view1 : TextView = TextView(this)
myLayout.addView(view1)
view1.layoutParams.height = (Height * 0.35).toInt()
view1.layoutParams.width = (Width * 0.8).toInt()
view1.x = (1+ Width*0.10).toFloat()
view1.y = (Height*0.15).toFloat()
view1.text = "Some text"
view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128,0,128))
```